# Need to compare datatables from multiple sources

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datatable, dataset

I am trying to compare DataTables and DataSets I have created from multiple sources. I have 1 DataSet created from an [ExcelDataReader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) library. The other sources of information are DataTables and come from the below code (I could make them DataSets instead of DataTables if that is more easier to work with):

```
    public DataTable ImportFromSQLDB()
    {
        SqlConnection sql;
        string query = "SELECT ClassandSubClass FROM dbo.ClassCodes";
        sql = new SqlConnection(@"server=1.1.1.1;" + @"Trusted_Connection=false;" + @"uid=user;" +
                                @"password=password;" + @"database=Depot;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sql);
        DataTable sqlds = new DataTable();
        sql.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(sqlds);
        sql.Close();
        return sqlds;          
    }

    public DataTable ImportFromSQLDB2()
    {
        SqlConnection sql;
        string query = "SELECT SubClassCodeDescription FROM dbo.ClassCodes";
        sql = new SqlConnection(@"server=1.1.1.1;" + @"Trusted_Connection=false;" + @"uid=user;" +
                                @"password=password;" + @"database=Depot;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sql);
        DataTable sqlds2 = new DataTable();
        sql.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(sqlds2);
        sql.Close();
        return sqlds2;
    }

    public DataTable ImportFromMySQLDB()
    {
        string conn = ("Data Source=1.1.1.1;" + "Database=platform;" + "Username=user;" + "Password=password;");
        MySqlConnection mysql = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        DataTable mysqlds = new DataTable();
        string cmd = "SELECT platformname FROM masterlist ";
        mysql.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
        da.Fill(mysqlds);
        mysql.Close();
        return mysqlds;
    }

    public DataTable ImportFromMySQLDB2()
    {
        string conn = ("Data Source=1.1.1.1;" + "Database=platform;" + "Username=user;" + "Password=password;");
        MySqlConnection mysql = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        DataTable mysqlds = new DataTable();
        string cmd = "SELECT codenameallsys FROM masterlist ";
        mysql.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
        da.Fill(mysqlds);
        mysql.Close();
        return mysqlds;
    }
```

I am wanting to create another method that performs a comparison on any 2 of the DataTables, but am lost as to how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of comparison did you have in mind?

Comment: Given that a `DataSet` is really just a container for one or more `DataTables` and the `DataRelations` between them, you can't "make them `DataSets` because the data data would still be in `DataTables` in those `DataSets` anyway.

Comment: Where the data comes from is irrelevant.  A `DataTable` is a `DataTable`.  Any comparisons will be the same whether the data has different sources or the same source.  All that matters is the logic of the comparison, which you have failed to mention.

Comment: i had wanted to compare my excel dataset with the importfromsqldb() dataset to match 1 column of information between the 2 datasets. then i needed the differences pulled to the side (perhaps in another dataset) for later use. i was able to complete what i needed with some help from a friend.